# How to fix images paths in CSS after IIS publishing?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm new with MVC (V4) and I have an issue after publishing my site to IIS.
My site works perfectly when viewed in IIS express though the web browser (and page inspector). However, when I publish my website (through VS2012) to IIS all my Images being references from my CSSs are broken.

My CSS folder is as follows:

```
ROOT\Content\MyCss
```

My Images folder is:

```
ROOT\Images\MyImages
```

**The folder structure is identical both on IIS virtual directories and my project directories.**

All my images are referenced like this:

```
../../Images/MyImages/image.jpg
```

When I change my CSS references to `../Images/MyImages/image.jpg` it starts to work again.
This does not consists to the actual physical folder paths of the IIS application/Virtual directory.

I will appreciate any help solving this out.

Comment: Have you used bundling to output your css? Probably, (yes I am only guessing) your bundled css is in `ROOT` location when Release profile is used. But when you are testing in Debug without the bundling, the links to the images are based on the path relative to `ROOT\Content\MyCss`.

Comment: Try using ~/Images and ~/Content if you're not ready for the bundling and minification framework.

Comment: Another thing to check is the virtual directory. See if there is `.` in it.

Comment: Yes I'm using bundling, but the same issue occurs when I remove the bundling and/or publish in debug mode. It is like it is using the "ROOT\Content" as the base relative path instead of "ROOT\Content\MyCss" folder. I was unable to use "~/". it only work at my chstml and not my css files. No "." in my virtual directory path as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bundles you should use ~/ eg. `@Styles.Render("~/bundles/stylebundle")` in your views.

When defining your bundles always start the file paths with ~/. eg

`bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/test")
.Include("~/content/test/test.css"));`

Any paths in your css should be relative to the css file itself.

eg `background-image: url('../../Images/test.jpg');`

I've just built a test site using the same structure you have and sticking to what I've written above and it all works in both debug and release. To fake the release mode on your local machine inyour bundle config file add

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```