# ISS Server not getting image path

Tags: asp.net, iis

In host IIS server of my asp.net web application , I had some problem. Background images are not displayed. How can i fix it, I'm trying to fix this but I'm unable to do it correctly. This is the code I have tried with.

```
body {width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Raleway;
  background: url('../../Img/TrellaborgAB.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

---

```
 <img src="../../img/powerdby.png" style=" margin-top:5px; float:right;margin-right:-7px; " />
```

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574119/relative-paths-in-iis-7-web-applications-under-a-website and this [How to fix images paths in CSS after IIS publishing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102547/how-to-fix-images-paths-in-css-after-iis-publishing)

Comment: @AshishSrivastava sir, i was read this, but not solved my problem,